# how to get all Arrays from JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get data from JsonObject like this :

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data_EN": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "url" :"http://exemple.com"
    }
  ],
  "data_FR": [...],
  "data_ES": [...]
}
```

I created a method to get this response , i can get only one array using `JSONArray` but i cannot found a method to get all data from this arrays

```
 ItemGroup itemGroup = new ItemGroup();
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data_EN");
 itemGroup.setTitle("data_EN");
 List<Data> items = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {
                            }.getType());

 itemGroup.setData(items);
 itemGroups.add(itemGroup);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating models:

> ItemResponse.class

```
public class ItemResponse {
    private String status;
    private List<Item> data_EN;
    private List<Item> data_FR;
    private List<Item> data_ES;
}
```

> Item.class

```
public class Item {
    private long id;
    private String url;
}
```

So you can then get it by:

```
ItemResponse itemResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), ItemResponse.class);
```

Comment: works ! but please edit your code and replace jsonArray.toString() with jsonObject.toString()  , it may help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Your sample JSON is invalid.

```
{

      "status": "ok",
      "data_EN": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "url" :"http://exemple.com", //<< remove this coma
        }
      ],
      "data_FR": [...],
      "data_ES": [...]
 }
```